# Automate depolyment to minikube using jenkins

Tags: python, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd

I created a simple python flask application that prints "Hello World!!".
I am using Ubuntu and have created the necessary files like Dockerfile and Deployment file in my local repository. The application works fine in my local machine, so I push the code along with all the necessary files to my GitHub repo to automate deployment to minikube by using jenkins CI/CD pipeline.
The pipeline should build docker image and push it to docker hub.
I have minikube installed in my local machine and its running fine.
Kindly explain the correct way to create a pipeline script to deploy the application.

Here is the source code along with the required files.

Source code-

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'Web app using python flask'
app.run(debug=True , host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Deploymentfile-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-app
          image: jeetlinux/docker-demo:v1

          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
            
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Dockerfile-

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
CMD python3 hello.py
```

How do I write a CI/CD pipeline to automate the build and deploy. Kindly explain with suggestion and example.
Everytime I try building it fails.Not able to resolve it.

Github repo where the files are:https://github.com/Biswajit1693/CI-CD-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Jenkins instance on your local machine and have it regularly poll the GitHub repo to see if there are any new changes. Note that while using a webhook would be more efficient since it can notify Jenkins instead of Jenkins having to continuously poll, you Jenkins instance would be on you local machine and it would be impossible for GitHub to access it unless you exposed it to the internet. Therefore, a method where your Jenkins instance polls the repo makes more sense.

Once the build is triggered, you can simply use kubectl commands to deploy the application to your minikube cluster. Both Jenkins and minikube run on the same machine, Jenkins should have access to the kubeconfig locally, meaning that you don't have to do any extra steps to get access to the cluster.

Comment: But minikube needs to be setup to configure in Jenkins. Earlier it was easy as there was a Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins now that plugin is suspended. I am running minikube on docker driver. Can you guide me the process to set up for deployment to minikube